# Trying to create loop in bash for a command that outputs a number when executed

Tags: postgresql, bash

I have been trying to create a loop in a bash to match the number that the command outputs and exits to another function.

command:

```
psql -d ct_fleet -t -c "select CASE when exists (select * from pg_stat_activity  where query like '%generate_trip_redo%' and state= 'idle' ) THEN 1 ELSE 255 END;"
```

the loop needs to execute the command and then move on to the next function when 255 is returned

I have tried multiple variations

```
while true ; do command;
if [ -eq 255 ]; then function
else sleep 20
fi 
done
```

this is however the first script that I am really focused on to build so very new to script writing

I have tried multiple variations

```
while true ; do command;
if [ -eq 255 ]; then function
else sleep 20
fi 
done
```

the loop needs to execute the command and then move on to the next function when 255 is returned

Comment: please update the question with the code you're using to capture the `psql` output (or is that part of your question?); if you're asking how to capture the `psql` output then update the question with the *complete* output from the `psql` command; as for your current code ... it should be generating an error ... so consider adding the complete error(s) to the question

Comment: @Conradb – Why do you write "_I have tried multiple variations_" twice without any variation?

Comment: @markp-fuso the psql command's is 1 if the query is matched and 255 if there was no match. my script calls a psql function that rebuilds trip data and exits but the process carries on in the background. So I am trying to wait for it to complete before executing the next function in the script.

Comment: @Armali I just mean that I have completely run into a wall with the loop and need help

Comment: as currently coded the `psql` command is going to send all output to stdout (ie, print the results on your terminal); in order to 'test' those results later in your script you first have to insure you are capturing the `psql` output, either in a file or a variable (eg, `psql ... > psql.out` or `result=$( psql ... )`); follow-on scripting would then access this file/variable to perform the desired tests (eg, `if [ "${result}" -eq 255 ]; then ...` (this assumes that the actual contents of `request` is in fact a single integer *and* it doesn't contain other stuff like a SQL result header)

Comment: if this still doesn't make sense then please update the question with the *complete* output from `psql` command; if we can see the *complete* output then I'm sure many of us can come up with suggestions on a) capturing the output in a format that b) can then be tested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to test on `-eq 255`, you need  to specify what you want to test on that value. For example a variable `a`:

```
if [ $a -eq 255 ] ; then
```

`-eq` is a binary operator, which means that it requires 2 operands.

So, how do you get the output of a command in a variable? This is done with

```
variable=$(command)
```

With all that, your loop will be something like

```
while true ; do
    cmdout=$(command)
    if [ $cmdout -eq 255 ] ; then
        function
    else
        sleep 20
    fi 
done
```

Comment: I did not think of setting the variable in the do, thank you will try it